# Detect IE Version, take screenshot, and print screenshot automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, screenshot

I need to do a few things in one javascript solution.

1. Must first detect the IE browser version (this I can do myself)
2. Must use javascript to take a screenshot of the active page.
3. Must print the screenshot that javascript just took.

I just cannot figure out how to do #'s 2 and 3. I have looked at the other articles about #2 on StackOverflow, but they all save an image, and I want to print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot capture a screenshot of the browser, using JS alone. To print something, you should invoke window.print(), on the window containing the things you want printed.

Comment: The problem I am working around is the JQplot printing issue with IE 7. None of the solutions on Stackoverflow work for me because the js file has been modified too many times for a practical implementation

Answer (score 0):

You can't take a screenshot from pure JS - you need a plugin.

Take a look [here](http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/10/14/how-snapabug-works/) if you want some details.

Update: Apparently you can do this with canvas to some degree, so in HTML5 capable browsers, you can use pure JS with a fallback to flash in older browsers. (See [here](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/))

Comment: Does not need to be pure JS. It does however need to be easy to implement for a person who knows absolute zilch Java